# limiter settings for recording dialog

Tags: compression, location, dialogue-recording, limiters

I need some help with getting the best release time for my Zoom F8's DIGITAL limiters.
I know they don't actually limit the analog audio, and that the AD Converters are clipping, but I at least want the mix I'm sending the cam to sound as good as possible.

I'm working on a lot of reality TV location sound gigs, and the Final mix guy wants my Cam mixes to be between -12db to 0db FS, averaging at -6db  He doesn't mind clipping, as he apparently has a plugin to help with that, and being reality TV, the clipping sound adds to the reality feel. There's also no budget to always sync up the audio in post, so they are using our cam mix's in final mix, unless there is major problems they are forced to sync up. (This goes against my sound philosophy but hey, if that's what they pay me to give them, that's what I'll give them)

Unfortunatly quantity is more important that quality, but I at least wanna give my best under the circumstances.

Comment: Everything in me is screaming, "Record it how you normally would; push it in post to the levels he wants. Don't tell him what you did."

Comment: Is there a good reason not to handle this in post before delivery?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I freelance, and we shoot sometimes shoot 5-6 days is

Answer (score 1):

After referencing [the manual for the Zoom F8](https://www.zoom.co.jp/sites/default/files/products/downloads/pdfs/E_F8.pdf), I did not find any "[make-up gain](https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/makeup-gain/)" function, but it does have an [input limiter](https://www.zoom.co.jp/sites/default/files/products/downloads/pdfs/E_F8.pdf#page=60) which needs to be enabled to function.

With that setting enabled you should be able to follow the instructions to set the threshold and then increase the input gain/trim setting to get a higher recorded signal.

---

Alternatively, this can all be accomplished by running your recordings through a DAW before delivery and using compression to achieve the same effect without needing to record so hot.